# bazel targets that are lazily built

Tags: java, scala, build, bazel

I'm using "[bazel-deps](https://github.com/johnynek/bazel-deps)-like" solution to keep my maven third party jars. in a pair of `maven_jar` repository rule and `java_import` rule.
As part of a big organisation I sync all of our managed dependencies to the workspace. That makes me having a lot more dependency targets that I actually use.

The problem is when running `bazel build //...` - it refers to all `java_import` (or `scala_import`) and downloads all jars (even those I don't need).

How can I tell bazel to build those third party targets only if referred in the other targets.

One very ugly solution I can think of is to move all internal targets to one main folder:

```
+ third_party
  | - com
  | - org
+ internal
  | - module-a
  | - module-b
```

and then I can build only my internal targets by running `bazel run //internal/...` But it's far from being elegant.

I'd be happy to have some kind of flag on targets that I don't want to be built unless directly or transitively required by targets that do not have this flag.

Comment: Are you saying that the pair of `maven_jar` and `java_import` rules import all the deps? Can you split them up into a maven jar/Java import per dep?

Comment: Also, your ugly solution is not ugly at all. It's the convention that most Bazel projects follow. Separating your source and external dependency is generally a good idea for projects using Bazel.

Answer (score 3):

> Targets with tags=["manual"] will not be included in wildcard target patterns (..., :*, :all, etc). You should specify such test targets with explicit target patterns on the command line if you want Bazel to build/test them.

https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/user-manual.html#target-patterns